# Get by reflection properties of class ,but not from inherited class

Tags: c#, reflection

```
class Parent {
   public string A { get; set; }
}

class Child : Parent {
   public string B { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get only property B, without property A
 but

```
Child.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
```

return both properties :/

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You should add **[BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)** to your flags, i.e:

```
typeof(Child).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

Comment: Can this the other way arround. Parent.GetProperties() and get all properties from the parent and child if the specific object is inherited by the child

Answer (score 12):

Try using the DeclaredOnly binding flag. It should limit the properties returned to only those declared on the class you are interested in. 
And here is a code sample:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Child).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Comment: This worked nicely. I had to included Instance here to get the props, I tried first BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly and could not understand why I got empty results.

Answer (score 6):

From **Type.cs**  : In this case use the DeclaredOnlyLookup

```
  private const BindingFlags DefaultLookup = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;
  internal const BindingFlags DeclaredOnlyLookup = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll use this approach and define my own const BindingFlags. +1 for looking into the source code.

Answer (score 4):

Add `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`