# How can I check if all values of properties is null or empty, but only in child class? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection

Currently I'm using reflection to check the values if its null or empty.
What I want to do is, I want to check all the values of properties from the child class only.

Here is my Parent Class:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public int is_hidden { get; set; }
    public string created_by { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_date { get; set; }
    public string last_modified_by { get; set; }
    public DateTime? last_modified_date { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Child Class

```
public class company : BaseModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string company_name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what I did now

```
public class Validation<T> where T : class, new()
{
    ResultStatus rs = new ResultStatus();
    public ResultStatus Validate(T ModelName)
    {
        if (typeof(T).GetProperties().All(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(ModelName) != null))
            return rs;
        else
            rs.SetSuccessStatus();
        return rs;
    }
}
```

Actually it works well, but my Validation Method is getting whole properties from both of parent and child classes.

I need suggestion how can I get the child class only, or something like exclude the parent class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get by reflection properties of class ,but not from inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596162/get-by-reflection-properties-of-class-but-not-from-inherited-class)

Comment: Oh this is exactly what i'm looking for, thx for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` in `GetProperties()` method to `Inherited` members are not considered

```cs
public ResultStatus Validate(T ModelName)
{
    if (typeof(T)
       .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance| BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
       .All(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(ModelName) != null))
          return rs;
     else
          rs.SetSuccessStatus();
     return rs;
}
```